# Tensorflow gpu not available for jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, jupyter, nvidia, cuda

I am trying to make `tensorflow` work with gpu support.

First I have `tensorflow-gpu` installed:
[image]

However, there is no gpu available. When I run the `nvidia-smi` and `nvcc --version` in terminal, I get:

[image]

So, my driver and cuda toolkit are available. Can anybody explain why is the gpu not available to tensorflow?

**Edit**: my `tensorflow` version is 2.8.0 and my `python` version is 3.7.3

Answer (score 1):

The nvidia-smi is not likely to show any usage of the GPU until you actually load something into it in your notebook.
There are many reasons why the gpu is not detected in keras. The easiest solution I think is to follow the installation steps carefully from scratch:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late for OP but I had the same issue (same code on console gives a GPU but nothing on jupyter), here is what I did:

- check that your python is the same for jupyter and on console: `!which python` (jupyter) must be the same as `which python` (console)
- check GPU compatibility with tensorflow, you need to install cuda and cudnn (apparently you got this: in my case I installed cudnn with `pip install --user nvidia-cudnn-cu11`, check this version with `nvcc --version`)
- uninstall jupyter and reinstall it (if you installed tensorflow with `sudo` do the same with `jupyter` and then open it with `sudo jupyter notebook`, I  personally use `pip install -user jupyter`; in case you have problems removing jupyter install `pip install pip-autoremove` (`sudo` or `--user` flag you chose but be consistent, you can also create a new python `venv`, which is recommended)

I didn't installed `tensorflow-gpu` and the GPU was detected. For more information:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip